# New instance of class in different namespace PHP

Tags: php, class, namespaces, instantiation

Here is my file structure (Laravel 5.2)

/app/http/middleware/Site.php (file one)

/resources/views/layouts/Automotive/text/DefaultText.php (file two)

I have the first file namespaced at `App\Http\Middleware`

I want to create a new instance of class `DefaultText` (file two) from within file one.

Doing this does not work:

```
$config_class = "\\Resources\\Views\\Layouts\\Automotive\\Text\\DefaultText";
new $config_class();
```

And this does not work either:

```
$config_class = "\\resources\\views\\layouts\\Automotive\\text\\DefaultText";
new $config_class();
```

In both instances, it states:

```
Class '\Resources\Views\Layouts\Automotive\Text\DefaultText' not found
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There can be many reasons why. 1. You haven't added the `/resources`-folder to be mapped to a namespace in the `"autoload": { "psr-4": { ... }}`-part in your composer.json. 2. You haven't added the correct namespace to your DefaultText-class file. 3. You're not using the same casing (the folder names and the namespace must contain the exact same casing).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try adding to autoload, I didn't do that.

Comment: That was it!!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the `/resources` folder to be mapped to a namespace in the `"autoload": { "psr-4": { ... }}` part of my composer.json file.

Thank you [Magnus Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson) for the help!